# Wordpress newbie, keeping getters the following errors when installing themes and plugins

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm currently developing 2 sites using Wordpress and hosted by a shared host who was recommended to me by a couple different WP fanatics.

Site 1 will be a medium-high volume blog.  With my shared host's 1-click install, it came with the plugin **W3 Total Cache**, which by everything I read, is the best out there.

2 problems.  For one, every time I upload a theme, I get the following error in admin:

Any time I try to change the settings in W3 Total Cache, I get about 15 to 20 of the following errors in admin:

```
Notice: get_theme is deprecated since version 3.4! Use wp_get_theme( $stylesheet ) 
instead. in /home/jpweber/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2824

Notice: get_themes is deprecated since version 3.4! Use wp_get_themes() instead. in 
/home/jpweber/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2824
```

And no matter what theme I install, I get the following 3 errors at the top of every page on the website:

```
Notice: add_custom_background is deprecated since version 3.4! Use add_theme_support( 
'custom-background', $args ) instead. in /home/jpweber/public_html/wp-includes  
/functions.php on line 2824

Notice: get_theme_data is deprecated since version 3.4! Use wp_get_theme() instead. in 
/home/jpweber/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2824

Notice: Undefined variable: output in /home/jpweber/public_html/wp-content/themes/respo
/functions/theme-actions.php on line 138
```

I've made no changes to functions.php, and I've downloaded fresh copies of functions.php, and I've checked the functions.php file to see if any of the answers on the author's homepage applied, but I've came up with no answers.

**UPDATE:**

For reference, here are my lines 2821-2828 in functions.php:

```
// Allow plugin to filter the output error trigger
if ( WP_DEBUG && apply_filters( 'deprecated_function_trigger_error', true ) ) {
    if ( ! is_null($replacement) )
        trigger_error( sprintf( __('%1$s is <strong>deprecated</strong> 
      since version %2$s! Use %3$s instead.'), $function, $version, $replacement ) );
    else
        trigger_error( sprintf( __('%1$s is <strong>deprecated</strong> 
    since version %2$s with no alternative available.'), $function, $version ) );
    }
    }
```

And in my theme_actions.php file, this is line 138:

```
$output .= ' {font:'.$font_nav["style"].' '.$font_nav["size"].'px/1.5em 
    '.stripslashes($font_nav["face"]).';color:'.$font_nav["color"].'}' . "\n";
```

Comment: And this is why WP websites always really suck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notices kind of tell you what to do, they are pretty descriptive.
Either you follow up on the notices, or set your error level lower than notice, so the messages won't show up anymore (not recommendedd though)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to check out my issue, dmaij.  When I do open up a php editor and check out the file ... for instance, there's this error at the top of every page -- in admin and in production -- Notice: Undefined index: fav_icon in /home/jpweber/public_html/wp-content/themes/catch-box/inc/theme-options.php on line 1158 ... I go to the top of that line, and it doesn't really offer how to fix it.

Comment: Sorry, took a while to find the problem. The problem lies in W3 total cache who is calling deprecated functions. I'm worried more about the undefined output. I think you have to run through the sources and fix the problems as suggested by wordpress...

Comment: Hi dmaij; not a problem.  I just appreciate that you're trying to help!  I just updated the question to include lines 2821-2828.  I just don't have any idea how to alter the code, given the error messages I'm receiving.

Comment: The lines reported are the lines that trigger the deprecated message, not the lines that call the deprecated function. I looked into W3 and saw 52 occurrences in the latest version. You should be able to edit these using the plugin editor in the WP admin interface.

Comment: Okay, I'll fiddle around in my admin with the W3 settings.  Thanks again Dmaij.  I just posted the undefined output error in my question, too.

Comment: remove the . in .= and it should be better. To be sure, check if the code above it does not contain $output.

Comment: Do you mean remove the entire line, $output .= ' {font:'.$font_nav["style"].' '.$font_nav["size"].'px/1.5em 
    '.stripslashes($font_nav["face"]).';color:'.$font_nav["color"].'}' . "\n"; ????

Comment: no, just the '.' in the '.=' operator following $output. so that is becomes $output = {.... The .= operator is a string concatenation, but if there is no string, you cannot concatenate.

Comment: I did as you instructed, but now it's giving me this in the admin area: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /home/jpweber/public_html/wp-content/themes/respo/functions/theme-actions.php on line 138 .... I really do appreciate your help, dmaij. I'm sure I'll figure it out via trial and error!

Comment: My bad, the single quote (') between the = and the { should be returned so you get $output = '{ etc. Sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Dmaij; it appears to be working now.  Appreciate your time in helping me out!